# Sitecore - protect page and child pages except for Sitecore group

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc

Using Sitecore 8, build 3, MVC.  I have a page (yourDomain.com\MustBeSecure) on a Sitecore 8 site and I do NOT want any users to access this unless they are in a specific security group ("sitecore\IhaveAccess").

I've looked into Content Editor for the item, clicked on the Security profile tab but believe that is for content editing.

Any help is appreciated on this.

**/////////  Update - Now working  /////////**
I should have noted we are using Active Directory with auto authentication.  Per Martin's post I started looking @ **Access viewer**

** please note on these screen shots I overlay the actual names of the pages (and group name) to test-page and secure page (and IHaveAccess)**.

Thanks for the assistance!!

Screen shot 1:
[image: ad\Everyone Access Viewer]

Screen shot 2:
[image: sitecore\Everyone]

Screen Shot 3: default\Anonymous
[image]

Screen shot 4: Security / Details from Content Editor for page[image: Security / Details from Content Editor for page]

Comment: What do you mean saying "unable to click the deny"? Did you try clicking that within Assign Security Rights screen (as on my second screenshot, and not the first one)? That screen is for setting permissions - it shows user/role and the item name as well as exact permission you set (and if that is recursive) .

Comment: Martin, Thanks for the quick response. I ended up being able to get the anonymous setup via the "assign Security rights". Added update #2 with screen shots. This is now working as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **Access Viewer** to achieve that (Sitecore --> Security Tools --> Access Viewer).

Select `default\anonymous` user (those are everyone who not logged in) then select your page, then click **Assign** and set `Deny` permission (you would probably also consider setting that recursively with setting **Inherintance** also to `Deny`).

Then pick up your role `Sitecore\IHaveAccess` and repeat previous step with setting `Allow` permission

[image]

And below is the screenshot of a dialog you get after clicking **Assign** button, there are actual permissions you set for the user / role, as well as inherritance.

[image]

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for the post, this confirms I was on the proper track.  I did not mention in post we are using Active Directory and auto authentication.  I ended up doing as you mentioned for the ad\Everyone Group and still do not get access denied.  I am going to update post with a few screen shots.